Preserving Cross-references links in an extracted PDF
When I write my lectures, I write them in one document such as this mwe
% document name : main.tex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contenu du chapitre]{%
    %\etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%
    \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \small }{}
    \localtableofcontents%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter one}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter one}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\end{document}

I continue to modify and expand upon this main.tex document and share the content with my students based on the progress of the lecture, typically chapter by chapter. So I create a new document that contains along the lines of this mwe :
% document name: pdf_chapter1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={3-5}]{main}
\end{document}

And share the compiled result. The workflow (is) was convenient because I've been doing it this way for many years, but the problem is that I lose all the links of cross-references of the chapters, table of contents, and equations in the document.
Could you help me solve this issue, or if not possible, suggest another workflow?

Is your whole document all on one .tex file or do you include smaller .tex files for the individual chapters?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Indeed, typically, I include chapter by chapter smaller documents into the main.tex.

Maybe you could use \includeonly to only compile a subset of the smaller tex files and then distribute the resulting pdf to your students?

A lot of time there somthing like "see theorem 1.2 page 3" (I use label and cross-reference commands) which reference a result from chapter one in, say, the second chapter. Although I loose link but at least the text makes it clear to which result I am referring to.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I modified the title and the question to clarify that I am talking about the cross-reference links.

including a PDF strips off annotions like links, you can reinsert them with the newpax package.

as Ulrike says you can use newpax, but why input the pdf, it is simpler to input the tex source, then the issue does not arise.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for the response. Just to make sure that I understand. If I incude the tex source of one chapter for example, I shoud manually account for page counter and chapter counter or there is a way to do this automatically ?

it depends what you want to do, clearly if you include pdf each chapter has the "original" page numbers so you have multiple page 1 (which may be confusing for the reader but may be what you want, it depends) if you include the tex source you can choose to have a continuous page number across all chapters or reset the page to 1 each time or explictly set it as chapter 3-page 1, ... or whatever you want,

I would suggest to use \includeonly to compile smaller parts of the document. Make sure to compile the whole document first, so that page numbers and cross-references in the smaller parts will be correct.
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contenu du chapitre]{%
    %\etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%
    \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \small }{}
    \localtableofcontents%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[]{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{cap1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter one}
\Blindtext
\[
  E = mc^{2}\label{eq}
\]
\section{section two of chapter one}
\Blindtext
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{cap2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\chaptertoc{} 
\section{section one of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\ref{eq}
\end{filecontents*}

\includeonly{cap2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\include{cap1}
\include{cap2}

\end{document}


Probably a mechanism similar to the \include/\includeonly mechanism might be nice.
A mechanism that also writes so-called checkpoints with counter values into auxiliary files in the event that things (fileparts instead of files) are not  processed for typesetting.
But with the following differences to the \include/\includeonly mechanism:

Instead of reading files with specific names, parts of a LaTeX file would be read, which are given names and which in the .tex-input-file are nested between a sequence \Filepart{⟨name of filepart⟩} and a sequence \EndOfFilepart.

Analogous to the command \includeonly{⟨comma list with the names of the files that are to be read in⟩}, there should be a command \OnlyFileparts{⟨comma list with the names of those fileparts that are to be read in for typesetting⟩}.

If a filepart should not be read in for typesetting, LaTeX would have to switch to verbatim mode and read from the file and create character tokens and throw them away until the sequence of character tokens
\EndOfFilepart
is found.

In the event that the content of a filepart is not typeset in the current LaTeX-run, but the associated auxiliary file that holds the data of cross-referencing labels and the like defined in this filepart is still read, there would have to be an optional argument, where, in the case that the hyperref package is loaded, one can specify the URL to another PDF file that contains this filepart, so that when cross-referencing cross-referencing labels that were defined in the non-typeset filepart, an external link to this other PDF file appears instead of an internal link with no destination (and thus with pdfTeX-engines destination auto-fixed to page 1).


With the following minimal working example a mechanism is fiddled together with the following two components:
\OnlyFilepart{⟨comma list with the names of those fileparts that are to be read in for typesetting⟩}
and
\Filepart[⟨URL of pdf-file containing this part⟩]{⟨name of filepart⟩}...\EndOfFilepart

\OnlyFileparts can only appear in the preamble of the main .tex-file.
With the \include/\includeonly-mechanism, the checkpoints have names that correspond to the names of the files. With the \Filepart...\EndOfFilepart/\OnlyFileparts-mechanism, the checkpoints are numbered consecutively starting with the number 1 and they and the associated auxiliary files/.aux files have names according to the scheme Filepart⟨number of the checkpoint belonging to the filepart⟩. In this way, several fileparts that in any case must be read in together, can have the same name.
The part of the mechanism that in the case of not typesetting a filepart reads that filepart verbatimized and creates character tokens and throws them away until the sequence \EndOfFilepart is found, does not read line by line, but character by character. On the one hand, no characters are lost in a line this way. On the other hand, the mechanism is slow on slow computers.
Don't nest fileparts inside fileparts.
\Filepart and the matching \EndOfFilepart must be in the same scope/group.
\Filepart and the matching \EndOfFilepart must be in the same .tex input file.
\Filepart[⟨URL of pdf-file containing this part⟩]{⟨name of filepart⟩}...\EndOfFilepart must occur neither in macro arguments nor in replacement texts of macros nor be component of values of token-registers and the like.
The code of the following minimal working example was written on a smartphone, where TeX Live 2020 was installed. It uses facilities provided by the expl3 programming envoronment. For testing it was compiled with pdflatex [pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex), LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4, L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>].
With more recent releases of LaTeX 2ε where the new hook-system is available, the \include/\includeonly-mechanism comes along with some hooks for carrying out some tokens each time including a file takes place. With the \Filepart...\EndOfFilepart/\OnlyFileparts-mechanism no hooks are implemented/the new hook system of LaTeX 2ε is not used. This is because the author of the initial release of this answer is not sufficiently used to LaTeX 2ε's new hook-system yet.
The \include/\includeonly-mechanism only works out when—before activating \includeonly— the entire document was compiled with all files included as many times as needed for obtaining the document with all cross-references etc matching out. Analogously the \Filepart...\EndOfFilepart/\OnlyFileparts-mechanism only works out when—before activating \OnlyFileparts—the entire document was compiled with all fileparts included as many times as needed for obtaining the document with all cross-references etc matching out.
The code has not been intensively tested. Use at your own risk.

\makeatletter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infrastructure for switching to verbatim-mode and gobbling things until encountering 
% \EndDocumentPart
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \UD@StringCase \str_case:nnTF 
\cs_new_eq:NN \UD@StringTail \str_tail:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \UD@IfEmpty \tl_if_empty:nTF
%\cs_new_eq:NN \UseName \use:c
%\cs_new:Npn \ExpandArgs #1
% {
% \cs_if_exist_use:cF { exp_args:N #1 }
% { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion } {#1} }
% }
%\msg_new:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion }
% { Unknown~arg~expansion~"#1" }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\UD@SwitchToVerbatimAndGgobbleToEndOfFilepart[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar=-1\relax
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\do\^^I\do\^^M% 
  \UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop{#1}{}%
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop[4]{%
  \if#4Z\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \endgroup
    \newcommand\UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop[3]{%
      \UD@StringCase{##2##3}{#1{#3}{\endgroup##1}}{}{%
        \UD@IfEmpty{##2}%
          {\UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop{##1}{##3}}%
          {\ExpandArgs{ne}\UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop{##1}{\UD@StringTail{##2}}{##3}}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop
    {#1#2}%
    {{#3#4}{\UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop{##1}{##2##3}}}%
    {#3#4}%
  }%
}%
\@firstofone{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\do\^^I\do\^^M%
  \UD@GgobbleToEndOfFilepartLoop{}{}{}%
}\EndOfFilepartZ%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infrastructure for patching/restoring \newlabel and \new@label@record:
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@Savednewlabel{}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@Savednew@label@record{}%
\newcommand*\UD@ResetNewlabelAndNew@label@record[1]{%
  \AtIfFilepartIncluded{#1}{}{%
    \csname @\ifx\csname ver@hyperref.\@pkgextension\endcsname\relax gobble\else firstofone\fi\endcsname
    {\let\newlabel\UD@Savednewlabel}%
    \let\new@label@record\UD@Savednew@label@record
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@SwitchNewlabelAndNew@label@record[2]{%
  \AtIfFilepartIncluded{#2}{}{%
    \csname @\ifx\csname ver@hyperref.\@pkgextension\endcsname\relax gobble\else firstofone\fi\endcsname
    {%
      \let\UD@Savednewlabel\newlabel
      \def\newlabel{\UD@Patchednewlabel{#1}}%
    }%
    \let\UD@Savednew@label@record\new@label@record
    \def\new@label@record{\UD@Patchednew@label@record{#1}}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@Patchednewlabel@AddURL{%
  \long\def\UD@Patchednewlabel@AddURL#1#2#3#4#5#6\\{{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@Patchednewlabel[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
  \expandafter{%
    \UD@Patchednewlabel@AddURL{#1}#3{}{}{}{}\\%
  }%
  {\UD@Savednewlabel{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@Patchednew@label@record[3]{%
  \UD@Savednew@label@record{#2}{#3{xr-url}{#1}}%
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infrastructure for \Filepart and \EndOfFilepart
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newwrite\UD@Filepartaux
\newcommand\UD@previous@auxout{}%
\newif\ifUD@FilepartSW\UD@FilepartSWfalse
\newcommand\UD@FilepartNesting{0}%
\newcommand\UD@FilepartList{}%
\newcounter{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\OnlyFileparts[1]{%
  \UD@FilepartSWtrue
  \let\UD@FilepartList\@empty
  \@for\reserved@a:=#1\do
  {%
    \ifx\UD@FilepartList\@empty
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\UD@FilepartList\expandafter{\reserved@a}%
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@FilepartList
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\UD@FilepartList\expandafter,\reserved@a}%
    \fi
  }%
}%
\@onlypreamble\OnlyFileparts
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\Filepart{om}{%
  \relax
  \xdef\UD@FilepartNesting{\the\numexpr((\UD@FilepartNesting)+1)\relax}%
  \ifnum\UD@FilepartNesting>1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \@latex@error{\string\Filepart\space cannot be nested}\@eha
    \UD@SwitchToVerbatimAndGgobbleToEndOfFilepart{\EndOfFilepart}%
  }%
  {%
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}\@ne
    \if@filesw
      \IfNoValueF{#1}{%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\UD@SwitchNewlabelAndNew@label@record{#1}{#2}}%
      }%
      \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@input{Filepart\arabic{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}.aux}}%
      \IfNoValueF{#1}{%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\UD@ResetNewlabelAndNew@label@record{#2}}%
      }%
    \fi
    \let\UD@previous@auxout\@auxout
    \@tempswatrue
    \AtIfFilepartIncluded{#2}%
    {%
      \let\@auxout\UD@Filepartaux
      \if@filesw
        \immediate\openout\UD@Filepartaux "Filepart\arabic{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}.aux"
        \immediate\write\UD@Filepartaux{\relax}%
      \fi
    }{%
      \UD@SwitchToVerbatimAndGgobbleToEndOfFilepart{%
        \deadcycles\z@
        \@nameuse{cp@Filepart\arabic{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}}%
        \let\@auxout\UD@previous@auxout
        \xdef\UD@FilepartNesting{\the\numexpr((\UD@FilepartNesting)-1)\relax}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\AtIfFilepartIncluded[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempswatrue
  \ifUD@FilepartSW
    \@tempswafalse
    \def\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\UD@FilepartList\do{%
      \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\EndOfFilepart{%
  \ifnum\UD@FilepartNesting=1 \expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
  {%
    \clearpage
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\UD@Filepartaux{\string\@setckpt{Filepart\arabic{UD@FilepartCheckpoints}}\@charlb}%
      {\let\@elt\@wckdocumentptelt \cl@@ckpt}%
      \immediate\write\UD@Filepartaux{\@charrb}%
      \immediate\closeout\UD@Filepartaux
    \fi
    \let\@auxout\UD@previous@auxout
  }%
  \ifnum\UD@FilepartNesting<1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@latex@error{Unmatched \string\EndOfFilepart}\@eha}%
  {\xdef\UD@FilepartNesting{\the\numexpr((\UD@FilepartNesting)-1)\relax}}%
}%
\newcommand*\@wckdocumentptelt[1]{%
  \immediate\write\UD@Filepartaux{\string\setcounter{#1}{\the\@nameuse{c@#1}}}%
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contenu du chapitre]{%
    %\etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%
    \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\small}{}%
    \localtableofcontents
}


%\OnlyFileparts{Lecture2}
%\OnlyFileparts{Lecture1}
%\OnlyFileparts{Lecture3,Lecture4}

\usepackage[pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Filepart{ToC}%
\tableofcontents
\EndOfFilepart
\Filepart[file:./Lecture1.pdf]{Lecture1}%
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter one}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter one}
\label{A label}%
\Blindtext
\EndOfFilepart
\Filepart{Lecture2}%
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter two}
\Blindtext
\EndOfFilepart
\Filepart{Lecture3}%
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter three}
\Blindtext
\ref{A label}%
%\expandafter\show\csname r@A label\endcsname
\section{section two of chapter three}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter three}
\Blindtext
\EndOfFilepart
\Filepart{Lecture4}%
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\chaptertoc{}
\section{section one of chapter four}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter four}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter four}
\Blindtext
\EndOfFilepart
\Filepart{Lecture2}%
\chapter{Chapter Five - should always go together with Chapter Two}
\chaptertoc{}
Chapter Five should always go together with Chapter Two, 
thus\verb|\Filepart|-commands get the same name.
\section{section one of chapter five}
\Blindtext
\section{section two of chapter five}
\Blindtext
\section{section three of chapter five}
\Blindtext
\EndOfFilepart
\end{document}

